# Gurobi Python API - How to add new variables to existing constraints

Tags: python, gurobi

I have built a decomposition algorithm using the gurobi python interface.

The algorithm involves adding **new variables** to already **existing constraints** of my model in each iteration. Right now I am reading the constraints from the model via `getConstrByName` and `getRow(constraint)`, add the new variables to the resulting linear expression, delete the old constraint and add the new constraint to the model. This procedure is extremely inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way to add new variables to existing constraints in a gurobi model?

Answer (score 0):

Call [Model.chgCoeff()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_chgcoeff.html) with the new variable, the constraint and the new coefficient.